# Get the resource in the MainWindow in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have added a `Cursor` file as a resource in my `MainWindow.xaml`, how can I access this resource from within a `Border` element that resides inside this window in code?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <FrameworkElement x:Key="OpenHand" Cursor="pack://application:,,,/Resources/openhand.cur"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="AppInterface">
     // A Border is added here by code
     // I want to be able to access the above resource from Border in code-behind
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this one :

```
var elementhand = Application.Current.MainWindow.Resources["OpenHand"] as FrameworkElement;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Application.FindResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.findresource.aspx)  to find them by name.

```
 FrameworkElement resource = Application.Current.FindResource("OpenHand");
```